# A property of Boolean algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

In a Boolean algebra $\mathcal B$, we know that
$$x+\bar{x}y=x+y\text{ for all } x, y\in \mathcal B.$$
By following the above identity, we can also write
$$xy+\bar{x}yz=xy+yz.$$
Can we write
$$\bar{y}xz+yp=xz+yp,\text{ where $p$ is distinct from $x$ and $z$}?$$
Or is there any alternative way to simplify the expression on the left side of the last equation further?

Comment: It would be good if you include in your question the steps to get what you wrote after "By following the above identity".

Comment: @JMP How, it is not true? In that case, both sides of the equation give you $1$.

Comment: @JMP These are logical operations and symbols, but not usual addition, multiplication or real number $1$ and $0$. $0$ and $1$ are just symbols.

Comment: @JMP You can't remove $z$ from the equation $xyz+x'yz=xyz+yz$ unless the structure is cancelative. However, such an equation will hold according to the second identity.

Comment: @JMP His answer is a counter example showing that the last identity doesn't hold. Thereby giving a good hint that the expression $\bar{y}xz+yp$ is in the most simplified form. The second identity which you are mentioning here is an already proven identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Taking $x = y = z = 1$ and $p = 0$, you get $\bar yxz +yp = 0$ but $xz + yp = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By the ways, do you mean that the expression $\bar{y}xz+yp$ cannot be further simplified?

Comment: I don't think that $\bar yxz + yp$ can be simplified.

Comment: Well. That's fine and it got my  problem  fixed. Thank you.